# Disable html-minifier from parsing attribute values

Tags: html, parsing, ecmascript-6, attributes, minify

My attribute has ES6 template value:

```
<span style="width:${Width}"> </span>
```

After minifying it becomes

```
<span style="width:{};"> </span>
```

I don't see an option to change this, seems like [html-minifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier) is evaluating that attribute value?

Test sample: https://replit.com/@DanDeancook/Disable-html-minifier-attr-parsing?v=1

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit, `minifyCSS` is default `true`, but documentation on project home page says `false`.

Set option `minifyCSS` to `false` and the template attribute value is kept as is.